# Conditional "multiple" attribute in <input type="file"> with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need an upload form field that may or may not allow the user to select more than one file.

I know I can do something like:

```
<input type="file" multiple ng-if="allow_multiple">
<input type="file" ng-if="!allow_multiple">
```

But, we know that is not ideal.

I tried

```
<input type="file" ng-multiple="allow_multiple">
```

But that doesn't work.

It seems that AngularJS [has no such ngMultiple directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/), but [everyone is using it anyway](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=ng-multiple&oq=ng-multiple&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2784j0j7&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) (or am I missing something?)

Anyway, what is the best way to accomplish that?

EDIT: From thw answers so far it really seems like there's no pretty way to do this.
I opened this issue on their tracker, let's see what we get :-)
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7714

Comment: have you considered ngUpload it has multiple as bool option?

Comment: ng-multiple works only for select.

Comment: @Dalorzo, you mean this, right? https://github.com/twilson63/ngUpload. Will take a look.

Comment: @Fals, do you know where can I find it (ng-multiple for <select>'s) in the official documentation?

Comment: you could try this one https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

Answer (score 7):

I come to this page for same issue with Angular 2

And finally fixed like this:

```
<input type="file" 
    [accept]="extAccepts" 
    [multiple]="(maxFiles > 1)" />
```

Note: both file type (extAccepts) and maxFiles are reading from component as @input() from the user.

Hope it will help for someone!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to write your own `ngMultiple` directive.

HTML (relevant):

```
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="allowMultiple"> Allow multiple</label>
<hr>
<input
  type="file"
  class="hide"
  accept="image/*"
  ng-multiple="allowMultiple">
```

JS:

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.allowMultiple = false;
    })
    .directive('ngMultiple', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                ngMultiple: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element) {
                var unwatch = scope.$watch('ngMultiple', function (newValue) {
                    if(newValue) {
                        element.attr('multiple', 'multiple');
                    } else {
                        element.removeAttr('multiple');
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ab2umXEFl93lo03G26ot?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Besides the difficulty of doing this there is also the issue that some browser will not evaluate `multiple="false"` (Safari 8 on file input for ex). So the multiple attribute needs to be conditionally written.

I would wrap your html in a directive and conditionally apply the attribute within the directive such as:

```
var input = elem.find('input');
if(condition)
  input.attr('multiple', 'true');
```

Where the condition could be any directive attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ng-attr-

```
 ng-attr-class="{{someBoolean && 'class-when-true' || 'class-when-false' }}"
```

If you prefix any attribute with ng-attr-, then the compiler will **strip** the prefix, and add the attribute with its value bound to the result of the angular expression from the original attribute value.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about ng-attr.

Now this is weird, look: I tried adding `ng-attr-multiple="{{allow_multiple}}"` on my <input>. It has no effect on it, regardless of the value of allow_multiple.
Now if I add `ng-attr-bolinha="{{allow_multiple}}"`, then it adds an attribute `bolinha="false"` or `bolinha="true"` on the <input>
But you know, even if it added multiple="false", the browser doesn't care for the "false" attribute, it would still allow for multiple file selection just because "multiple" is present.

Mmm, I have the feeling this should be easier. I'm heading to the issue tracker...

Answer (score 0):

I am on mobile, sorry for the short answer.

I would hide two different file inputs, one with the multiple attribute and one without. You can use the ng-if directive to achieve that.

Edit: I'm so sorry, seems like you don't want to do it that way, even though it's completely valid.
You could write your own directive for it however, it's really simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngSwitch directive for this. Take a look in AngularJs documentation for more details.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

In this demo example the directive switch between input file with and without multiple based in a scope param passed for directive using ngSwitch directive.

[Demo using ngSwitch](http://plnkr.co/edit/23KZ6Y1kM13GuxXu67Iq?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Wilson. It solves the problem, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. It's no different than using ng-if (I have to declare two inputs anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to use ngShow/ngHide for this. In this demo example input file is show/hide based in param and have a directive for get input value(s) and set in a $scope param.

[Demo using ngShow + directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/SWIutJLG8zspftQMPNb9?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Wilson. It solves the problem, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. It's no different than using ng-if (I have to declare two inputs anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is pretty simple since you are using directive or component - just manipulate DOM on the right moment. Take a glance here:

```
app.component('myComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'tmpl.html',
    bindings: {
        str: '@'
    },
    controller: function ($element) {
        this.$postLink = function () {
            $element.find('input').attr('multiple', 'multiple');
        }
    }
}
```